# merge these two sets of code so i can retrieve the players for two services using $player code i have in different code

Tags: video-streaming

we don't have to edit the $player code but mostly i want to combine the code for checkTV and CheckForMovie function in these two code and return respective data for to respetive player

mostly i need these code to be combined and there should be two return values one for superembed and one for smashystream for both checkTv and checkForMovie

first set is

```
first set is

["


    public function checkTv( $post ) {

        if ( ! empty( $post['temporada'] ) ) {
            $ids          = $post['ids'];
            $superembed = '/se_player.php?video_id='.$ids.'&tmdb=1&s='.$post['temporada'].'&e='.$post['episodio'] ;
        }

        return $superembed;
    }

    public function checkForMovie( $post ) {


        return '/se_player.php?video_id='.$post['ids'];


    }
    
    "]


        if ( ! empty( $post['temporada'] ) ) {
            $ids          = $post['ids'];       
            $smashystream = 'https://embed.smashystream.com/playere.php?tmdb='.$ids.'&season='.$post['temporada'].'&episode='.$post['episodio']; 
        }

        return $smashystream;
    }

    public function checkForMovie( $post ) {


        return 'https://embed.smashystream.com/playere.php?tmdb='.$post['ids'];


    }

"]
```

I tried using case and conditions but it didn't work